AWS Cloudfront: POST and GET return 504 and 403 depending on the browser
We have an Spring boot server that has been working well the last years. A few days ago it started returning a 504 Gateway Timeout ERROR sending a request with Postman (Windows, Firefox). The reply is received instantaneously. The call does not expect the reply from other server or anything, even the simplest status check returning an ok fails the same way. Is the only thing running in the server, so no possibility of overload.I checked the CPU usage and was basically idle.
I tested in other computer (Ubuntu, Firefox) and there it says "403 The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country", which is not true because my country is still there in the allow list.
There were changes in the code lately but nothing that I could associate with that kind of fail. Locally runs well. I know very little of AWS, I inherited all this setup. Could somebody guide me to diagnose what is exactly happening? I would like to identify if it is a problem in my code (that appears in the server but not locally) or if it is an AWS thing.

What do you have in CloudWatch ?

"No data available". Probably because when you told me is the first time I enter there, and I guess one must configure that somehow to track, right?

Finally hired support since I was in a hurry. Seems that at some point the port set somewhere in Docker (don't ask me where exactly) was changed and was not anymore the one set also in CloudFront associated to the instance. This was discovered with the command: docker ps
Which printed something like: 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp, :::8081->8080
8081 was the value in the Docker configuration, but in CloudFront we had a 8080. I changed this last to 8081 too and now it works.
Certainly the error messages were quite confusing.
